# Number of coin tosses needed to establish bias

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

Say, you toss a coin and see tails, and repeat the toss. How many consecutive tails would you need to establish that a coin is biased ($P_\textrm{heads} < 0.5$)

Null: $P_\textrm{heads} = p = 0.5.$

So need $(1-p)^n < 0.05$ to establish bias at $95\%$ confidence one sided
\begin{align}
\implies 0.5^n &< 0.05\\\implies n &> \frac{\log(0.05)} {\log(0.5)}
\\\implies n &\geq 5.
\end{align}
So, it seems like we only need $5$ tails to conclude that coin is biased? That seems very low. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The plot at the end of my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/620591/919 is relevant: it graphs the chance of obtaining a run of $k$ tails in $100$ tosses (and gives a procedure to do this calculation for any number of tosses).  The solution is amenable to asymptotic analysis, showing the correct expression to use in place of "$(1-p)^k$" (which does not account for the number of tosses and therefore cannot be correct).

Answer (score 1):

Comment.

Yes. However, you'd have to be really careful how you used
this criterion of getting five Tails in a row to declare a coin
as biased. (More-straightforward tests look at the overall balance between
Heads and Tails.)

In the experiment below, I simulated 1000 tosses of a *fair* coin.
The longest run of Tails in those 1000 tosses was of length 8.
The R procedure `rle` counts runs of Heads (`1`'s) and Tailz (`0`'s).

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rbinom(1000, 1, .6)
rle(x)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:511] 1 5 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
  values : int [1:511] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...
max(rle(x)$len[rle(x)$val==0])
[1] 8
```

This same sequence of 1000 tosses happened to have a run of 10 Heads.

```
max(rle(x)$len[rle(x)$val==1])
[1] 10
```

Comment: Good point, however, I was mainly implying that you tossed n times, and only observed tails- not that you observed n consecutive tails in a longer chain of tosses. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I guessed that's want you intended. But it might be a slippery slope. What if you got a run of _six_ Tails after seeing just one Head?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than counting tails, I would prefer to calculate a minimum sample size to conclude whether the coin may be biased. Here is one way this can be done, using Chebyshev's inequality. The following formula uses this inequality to get a sample size needed to estimate a mean that is within $\epsilon$ of the true one with probability $1-\delta$, given that we have an upper bound on the variance $\sigma^2$: $$ceil(\frac{\sigma^2}{\delta\epsilon^2}).$$

In this case, the variance $\sigma^2$ is bounded above by 1/4, which is the maximum variance a Bernoulli random variable can have, namely the variance for a fair coin ($(1/2)(1-1/2)$).

For example, we choose $\epsilon=1/10$ and $\delta=1/20$ (so we have a 95% confidence interval that the probability would be between 4/10 and 6/10 if the coin were fair), then we should flip the coin at least—$$t=ceil(\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{20}*(\frac{1}{10})^2}) = 500$$ times, count the number of heads, and divide by the number of flips to get the estimated probability of heads, which will be within 1/10 of the true probability at a 95% or greater chance.

Another way is Hoeffding's inequality. Using the same notation as before, the sample size for random variables in [0, 1] (including Bernoulli random variables) is— $$ceil(\frac{\ln(2/\delta)}{2\epsilon^2}), $$ so that the same example becomes— $$ceil(\frac{\ln(2/\frac{1}{20})}{2(\frac{1}{10})^2}) = 185.$$

See also the reference below.

Actually the exact minimum sample size for $\epsilon=1/10$ and $\delta=1/20$ is 101.  Chen (2011) provided a computational method for computing the minimum sample size as well as a table for common $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ combinations.

REFERENCES:

- Jiang, L., Hickernell, F.J., "Guaranteed Monte Carlo Methods for Bernoulli Random Variables", arXiv:1411.1151 [math.NA], 2014.
- Chen, Xinjia. "Exact computation of minimum sample size for estimation of binomial parameters." Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference 141, no. 8 (2011): 2622-2632.

Comment: A large enough $N$ would allow one to detect a trivial bias.  It would be perhaps more informative to decide on the minimum level $b$ of bias that matters and compute a Bayesian posterior probability that $P_{heads} > b$.