# What test to use in order to conclude that a number of seeds/experiments is enough?

Tags: probability, experiment-design, statistical-power, monte-carlo

When performing a series of replicas for an experiment with a stochastic component  (e.g. a Monte Carlo experiment, training a machine learning model, etc.) and averaging the results - how can I determine that I can stop at that number of replicas?

Is there a statistical test to determine, say, that after running `n` replicas of an experiment and getting the result μ<sub>n</sub>±σ that the results of running `N` replicas (with `N>>n`) would average μ<sub>N</sub> such as
μ<sub>n</sub>-σ< μ<sub>N</sub> < μ<sub>n</sub>+σ with probability `p`?

Comment: This is related to [tag:power-analysis].

Comment: Thanks.
I have added the `statistical-power` tag.

Comment: This is a matter of finding a sample size needed for a specific confidence interval.  In general, an known upper bound on the variance (or another moment) is needed.  Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158937 , https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525490 .