# Analytic expression for false-negative rate of binomial tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution, false-positive-rate

I wrote a [previous question yesterday](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552247/how-many-coin-flips-are-needed-to-distinguish-an-unfair-coin-with-a-simultaneous?noredirect=1#comment1015223_552247) which was maybe too long and boring to read. So to try to get an answer, I've boiled down my question to something short and specific which is:

**Is there an analytic expression for false-negative rate of binomial tests as a function of number of coinflips and weight of the unknown coin?**

That is, if I have a coin that has a chance of $(50-\epsilon)\%$ and $(50+\epsilon)\%$ for heads and tails, what is the chance that I won't get a false-positive for a specific confidence level?

To give a specific example to make it more clear: I have an unfair coin with a 90$\%$ chance of Heads. I can sample my coin by flipping it N times, and want to decide on a value of N that confirms it for a specific confidence level (low false-positive rate). If my p-value that I choose is very small (a high confidence level), then it means without taking a lot of data my false-negative rate is high. That is, I can be looking at my unfair coin data, but my binomial test returns a p-value greater than my confidence level and I cannot conclude my data represents flips from an unfair coin.

Therefore, I want to know how to figure out what my false-negative rate is as a function of number of coinflips and weight of the unknown coin.

This way, if I have a coin of unknown weight, and want to test if it's fair, I can characterize how confident I am that it is not fair as a function of what the coins weight could be. The closer it is to 50/50 the less confident I am that it's correct.

Comment: If this is a replacement for your previous question, it would be best to paste it over that question as an edit.

Comment: I have a partly complete answer to your previous question, but it could use more focus. However, several issues in this version concern me; if your test is $H_0:p=\frac12$ (vs $H_1:p\neq\frac12$), then rejecting with a population proportion of $0.5+\epsilon$   would be a true positive not a false positive. If your true null is actually an interval, you should address that (but that situation would perhaps be more typically approached as an equivalence test instead).

Comment: Indeed, the previous version already has at least two distinct formulations of the question which you say are equivalent questions, but which are not. It may be better to focus on a single question, or alternatively perhaps to ask a more general question about how power calculations are typically done (with specific reference to testing fairness of a coin).