# Number of configurations in which you can roll 2 6's in a row

Tags: markov-process, combinatorics, dice

A colleague at work gave me a problem to think about.

If you throw $n$ dice, how many configurations are there where you get at least 2 6's in a row?

I worked a lot with Pascal's triangle and in the end found the following formula which works when compared to brute force calculations.

$$A(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}5^{n-2-i} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{\min(n-2-i,i)} {n-1-k\choose n-2-i-k} \right]$$

where $A(n)$ is the number of configurations for $n$ dice.

I don't really know how to prove it, could anyone give me an idea on where to start?

Here is the Python code for the implementation of the function.

```
import numpy as np
from math import comb
def analytic(n):
    no_wins = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        mult = 5**(n-2-i)
        sum = 0
        for k in range(min(n-2-i,i)+1):
            sum += comb(n-1-k, n-2-i-k)
        no_wins += mult*sum
    return no_wins
```

Comment: You can do much better than that: a closed form solution is $$A(n)=6^n-\frac{(123+55\sqrt 5)\lambda_+^n-(3+\sqrt5)\lambda_-^n}{120+54\sqrt 5}$$ where $\lambda_{\pm}=(5\pm 3\sqrt5)/2$ are the roots of the quadratic $x^2-5x-5.$ This can be found in many ways, but most of them begin with a recurrence relation. Consider splitting the configurations into those that end in a 6 and those that do not.  (The recurrence will look remarkably like this quadratic polynomial. ;-) Indeed, even if you ignore the second term in the numerator, you still obtain an answer to more than $0.84n$ significant figures.

Comment: It may be easier to find $6^n - $ the number with no consecutive sixes

Comment: @Henry Why?  The question isn't about counting all strings with fewer than 2 sixes.

Comment: @whuber Indeed it is not, but counting the strings with consecutive sixes can get more complicated than counting those without consecutive sixes. You in effect done that with your $6^n- \cdots$ expression where the $\cdots$ are [OEIS A180033](https://oeis.org/A180033) counting the number with no consecutive sixes

Comment: @Henry Ah, I see that I misread your comment: what I read as a *dash* is intended as a minus sign!  In other words, you intended your suggestion to read something like "It might be easier to count the configurations without any sixes in a row." And that approach indeed is reflected in the formula (which could algebraically be rewritten to bury the $6^n$ term, if one wanted).

Comment: @whuber Yes - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks for the closed form solution, really interesting to see there is one. My collogue indeed found the recursive equation solution, but didn't manage to convert that into the closed form solution. Quick question, is there a closed form solution if the question was at least k 6's in a row?

Comment: Yes.  In that case I would solve it using a Markov chain on $k+1$ states.  The states count the number of 6's in a row up to and including the immediately preceding rolls. The chain begins in state $0$ and for $s\lt k$ makes transitions from states $s$ to $s+1$ (with probability $1/6$) and $s$ to $0$ (with probability $1-1/6$). The state $s=k$ is an absorbing state. The closed-form solution therefore will be a linear combination of powers of roots of a polynomial of degree at most $k+1$ (and one root is known to be $1,$ so the degree is really just $k$).

Comment: Do you have an reference with the full proof using markov chains by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Before you roll the die you have observed $s=0$ sixes.  As you make each roll, keep track of the current run of sixes: if the roll is a six, increment $s$ and otherwise reset $s$ to $0.$  If you ever get to $s=2$ during your $n$ rolls you are done because you have observed two sixes in a row.

This describes a simple *Finite State Automaton,* or FSA, with the states $s\in\{0,1,2\}$ and transitions $0\to 0,$ $0\to 1,$ $1\to 0,$ $1\to 2,$ and $2\to 2.$  Additionally, because the inputs it receives (the rolls of the die) are independent, random, and uniformly distributed, this FSA makes transitions from state $i$ to state $j$ with unvarying probabilities $p_{ij}.$ This describes the *transition matrix* $\mathbb P$ with respect to the states $(0,1,2)$ where

$$6\,\mathbb P = (6\,p_{ij}) = \begin{pmatrix}5 & 1 & 0 \\ 5 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 6\end{pmatrix}$$

The starting state is $\mathbf s = (1,0,0):$ that is, $s=0.$  After $n$ transitions, the probability distribution of the states is the vector $\mathbf s\,\mathbb P^n:$ the first row of $\mathbb P^n.$  Thus, the chance the FSA is in state $s=2$ is the $1,3$ (upper right) entry of $\mathbb P^n.$  Because there are $6^n$ distinct equiprobable sequences of inputs to the FSA, the *number* of sequences with at least two sixes in a row is

$$A(n) = 6^n \left(\mathbb P^n\right)_{1,3}.$$

This analysis is almost trivial because it merely expresses how matrix multiplication mirrors the axioms of probability and the assumptions about the dice.  Where it becomes useful lies in the linear algebraic fact that there exists an invertible matrix $\mathbb V$ for which $\mathbb V^{-1} \mathbb P \mathbb V$ is *diagonal.*  That is, there exist (possibly complex) numbers $\lambda_i$ (the *eigenvalues*) for which

$$\mathbb P = \mathbb V\pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3} \mathbb V^{-1}.$$

In the repeated multiplications to compute $\mathbb P^n,$ there will be $n-1$ pairs of $\mathbb V\mathbb V^{-1}$ terms that cancel, leaving

$$\mathbb P^n = \mathbb V \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3}^n \mathbb V^{-1} = \mathbb V\pmatrix{\lambda_1^n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2^n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3^n}\mathbb V^{-1}.$$

*The diagonalization of $\mathbb P$ thereby reduces the computation of $\mathbb P^n$ to taking powers of individual numbers.*  Moreover, the matrix product exhibits the answer in *closed form* as a linear combination of the $n^\text{th}$ powers of the eigenvalues.

For this particular matrix $\mathbb P$ it turns out that

$$\mathbb V=\pmatrix{1 & \frac{1}{10}(5+3\sqrt5) & \frac{1}{10}(5-3\sqrt5) \\ 1&1&1 \\ 1&0&0}$$

and

$$\pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3} = \pmatrix{1&0&0 \\ 0&\frac{1}{12}(5+3\sqrt5)&0 \\ 0&0&\frac{1}{12}(5-3\sqrt5)}.$$

From this we may compute

> $$A(n) = 6^n\left(\mathbb P^n\right)_{1,3} = 6^n\frac{\left(54 \sqrt{5}-60\right) -\left(33+13 \sqrt{5}\right) \lambda_2^n + \left(93-41 \sqrt{5}\right) \lambda_3^n}{54 \sqrt{5}-60}.$$

Its values for $n=1,2,\ldots,8$ are

$$0,\ 1,\ 11,\ 96,\ 751,\ 5\,531,\ 39\,186,\ 270\,241,\ \ldots$$

It agrees with the output of the Python code in the question, strongly suggesting that code is correct.

(You can see the powers of the eigenvalues in the numerator of $A(n),$ if you imagine $\lambda_1^n=1^n=1$ multiplying the first term.  This is useful because for $n$ sufficiently large, $\lambda_2^n$ and $\lambda_3^n$ become vanishingly small, giving you a clear, quantitative asymptotic expression for $A(n):$ namely, $1-A(n) = O(\lambda_2^n) \approx O(0.9756837^n) = O(10^{-0.010691 n}).$)

As a check, let's interpret the smallest values:

- When $n=1$ there are $A(1)=0$ ways to get two sixes in a row.
- When $n=2$ there is $A(2)=1$ way, the sequence `66`.
- When $n=3$ there are $A(3)=11$ ways: the $5$ sequences `66*`, the $5$ sequences `*66`, and the sequence `666`.
- When $n=4$ the sequences are `66**`, `*66*`, `**66`, `66*6`, `6*66`, `666*`, `*666`, and `6666`. Those with two non-`6`s appear $5^2$ times while those with one non-`6` appear $5^1$ times.  Thus $A(4) = 5^2(3) + 5^1(4) + 5^0 = 96.$

*We begin to discern the sum in the question:* the power of $5$ must count the number of non-`6`s in the string while the sum of Binomial coefficients must be counting the possible patterns of their occurrences within the string.  (This provides some hints about how to demonstrate the correctness of that formula.)

---

Finally, here is an `R` implementation of a general-purpose solution.  The arguments of the function `f` are $n,$ $k$ (the number of sixes in a row), and $d$ (the number of faces on a die, where a "six" is understood to be some arbitrary designated face).  It's basically two lines:

1. Construct and diagonalize $\mathbb P$ using `eigen`.
2. Compute $\mathbb P^n.$

The `Re(zapsmall(...))` stuff gets rid of small floating point errors that creep in (by zeroing out relatively tiny values and retaining only the real part of a potentially complex number).  Although this works for arbitrarily large $n$ (where the summation in the question becomes unwieldy), special care in handling the floating point imprecision is needed.  (The basic idea is to replace $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ by zeros when $n$ is sufficiently large, because their powers will be vanishingly small, and either compute using logarithms or remove the `d^n *` factor to return the probability instead of the count, which will overflow for medium to large $n.$)

```R
f <- function(n, k = 2, d = 6) {
  with(eigen(rbind(cbind(d-1, diag(1, k)), c(rep(0, k), d)) / d), {
    V <- t(vectors)
    setNames(Re(zapsmall(sapply(n, \(n) d^n * solve(V, diag(values^n) %*% V)[k+1, 1]))), n)
  })
}
```

For example, `f(1:8)` outputs

> ```
>  1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8 
>  0      1     11     96    751   5531  39186 270241
> ```

As another example (to illustrate the flexibility of `f`), here it is used to plot the chances of observing runs of various lengths $k$ in 100 tosses of a fair coin (a `100d2`):

```R
k <- 1:15
p <- sapply(k, \(k) f(100, k, 2)) / 2^100
plot(k, p, main = "Chance of at least k 1's in a row for 100d2")
```

[image]

It is interesting that there's a non-negligible chance, greater than $1/754,$ of observing 15 ones in a row.

Comment: Wonderful answer!

Comment: Beautiful, Thank you!